# Visual Studio: how to control specific configuration parameters on student PCs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone tell me how to control default configuration parameters in VS 2017 C++?  The scenario is that we generate one sample PC with the software we want (Win10, VS2017, et cetera), and this image is cloned onto about 100 PCs in student CS labs.

The two specific things I would like to control are (1) use of precompiled headers and (2) message C4706 (= versus == in an if condition).  There are some others, but these are at top of the list.

I know students could fix this themselves, but so many are confused in the first few weeks of an introductory programming class that I don't want to try that.

A search of MSDN has not been productive, but I probably am using the wrong search terms.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could also edit the default platform property pages found at \\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0, Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props and Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props

I'm not sure how you would automatically distribute those files but so long as you are using MSBuild as the build system anything in those files is picked up prior to project-specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of:

- Change the default settings in [property pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/property-pages-visual-cpp) for each configuration
- Create a custom [project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates) with all the project settings necessary. This will only affect new projects created with this template. Also it will keep the default template intact and will probably allow students to experiment a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

For enabling Precompiled header.

Right click your project->Properties->( a property pages window appears)Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers -> (on the right side) Select `Use(/Yu)` by clicking **Precompiled Header**.

And for suppressing C4706, set compiler warning to level less than 4

Right click your project->Properties->( a property pages window appears)Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> General ->**Warning Level** to less than 4

**To retain the settings and share with others....**

I do not have proper VS2017.... Can you try as said below.....

First export the existing project settings using

project(visual studio menu)->Export template.... continue and and save the template and make a note of the path....

usually by default the templates is saved in below path as a zip file.

C:\Users\<>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates

Now copy the zip file and and put it in

C:\Users\<>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C++ Project

Check if your template is automatically picked up.

If not open visual studio command prompt tool and run

devenv /installvstemplates.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have tried this and it does not affect the defaults for the next new project.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please give a shot.